# for loops to recursion

Tags: arrays, list, loops, erlang

Im in the middle of my data structures course at uni and im trying to understand it. I have a general idea about recursion and loops in C but im having trouble understand how a loop would be implemented in erlang. For example i have the following loop from my a program of mine in c:

```
int ii;
double cos_lat[8];    
for(ii = 2, cos_lat[1] = cos(lat); ii <= 7;; ii++)
{
 cos_lat[ii] = cos_lat[1] * cos_lat[ii-1]
}
```

And i dont have any clue as to how it may be implemented in erlang. 
I know i have to create my own definition of a loop such as:

```
for(Max, Max, F) -> [F(Max)];
for(I, Max, F) -> [F(I)|for(I+1, Max, F)].
```

(Taken from pragmatic erlang)

And then call it as follows:

```
for(2,7,fun(ii) -> // this is where i get stuck.
```

I think i have to use a different data structure over an array such as a list but how i access the list im unsure of.

Thanks for the replies. Just an update (14/8). I have tried to make a recursion of the code as follows:

```
-module(cos1).
-export([cos_lat/1]).
cos_lat(Base, Iterator, Prev) -> [Base*Prev|cos_lat(Base,Iterator+1,Base*Prev)];
cos_lat(Base, 7, Prev) -> [].
```

and call it as follow:

```
cos1:cost_lat(cos(lat),2,cos(lat).
```

But it just doesn't want to work! Erlang is really a confusing language.

Comment: Note that this may not be the best way to understand the algorithm. You are probably better off in trying to understand what the algorithm *means* and reimplement it in a functional manner, rather than mechanically trying to port imperative code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at "for" loop structure.

It contains **initialization block**, **condition block** and **update block**. 
Loop has a **state** (which at the beginning is actually defined in initialization block). 
*No matter which data structures you want to process, because structure of loop in general would be the same. **Loop state** encapsulates actual data structure.*

Also, you may see that **condition block** and **update block** in general **are functions of loop state**.

Using this information, let's create generic loop function:

```
-module( loops ).
-export( [ for/3 ] ).

for( State, ConditionFunc, LoopFunc ) ->
        case ConditionFunc( State ) of
                true ->
                        NewState = LoopFunc( State ),
                        % next iteration
                        for( NewState, ConditionFunc, LoopFunc );
                false ->
                        % terminate and return
                        State
        end.
```

Example, lets create a list of numbers from 1 to 10 (in eralng shell), using our function:

```
1> c(loops). 
{ok,loops}
2> 
2> ConditionFunc = 
2> fun( { 0, List } ) -> false;
2> ( _ ) -> true 
2> end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.82930912>
3> 
3> LoopFunc = 
3> fun( { N, List } ) -> { N - 1, [ N | List ] } end. 
#Fun<erl_eval.6.82930912>
4> 
4> { _, Result } = loops:for( { 10, [] }, ConditionFunc, LoopFunc ).
{0,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]}
5> 
5> Result.
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
6>
```

It is not the best way to create sequence of numbers, it is only for illustration. Always you might find more elegant recursive solution vs. loop solution. For our example, next solution is more preferable:

```
seq( A, B ) ->
        my_seq( A - 1, B, [] ).

my_seq( A, A, List ) ->
        List;
my_seq( A, B, List ) ->
        my_seq( A, B - 1, [ B | List ] ).
```

In shell:

```
1> loops:seq( 1, 10 ).
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Or just use function from standard library lists :)

```
2> lists:seq( 1, 10 ).
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Comment: It's worth adding that since erlang has tail-call recursion your for loop example runs in constant space just like C's for loop does. This would not be true in javascript for example since the stack size would be the same as large as the number of loop iterations.

Answer (score 0):

At this point:

```
for(2,7,fun(ii) -> // this is where i get stuck.
```

your `fun` is being called with the index, but you're not actually interested in the index - you need the value that was added to the list in the previous iteration.  You could pass that as the fourth argument to your `for` function; the first time you call it, you'd need to seed it with `cos(lat)`, and use the new value in every recursion step.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anybody is interested. I solved the problem as follows:

```
    -module(cos_lat).
    -export([cos_lat/3]).

     cos_lat(_Base, _Iterator, _Prev) ->
     cos_lat(_Base, _Iterator, _Prev, []).

     cos_lat(_Base,0, _Prev, _Co) ->
     lists:reverse(_Co);

     cos_lat(Base, Iterator, Prev, Co) -> 
     cos_lat(Base, Iterator-1, Base*Prev, [Prev*Base|Co]).
```

So to call this you would enter:

```
     cos_lat:cos_lat(math:cos(lat),7,math:cos(lat)).
```